# Esper: detect event start only

Tags: esper, nesper

I'm new to Esper (NEsper, actually) and I've been trying (unsuccesfully) to create an statement to detect when an event starts.

For example, suppose I have an event type called "Started betting" and I want to consider it is happening after 10 minutes of having "proof" of that. With what I've been using as the statement, after 10 minutes the `update()` method is triggered every time there is "proof".

I've tried something like

```
from (...), StartedBetting as st 
where st is null AND (...)
```

but didn't work (event was never detected).

Hope I've made myself clear.

Any hints will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you right, when receiving any start-betting event you simply want to delay for 10 minutes and then get called? The "proof" part is not clear. But this would do it:

```
select * from pattern [every StartBetting -> timer:interval(10 min)]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I'll try to explain the proof part: proof could be something like a discount in a bank account. I don't want to receive a "start-betting" event for every discount, but for multiple consecutive in a short period of time. However, once received, I don't want to receive any other of this type (the person has already started betting). That's why, sadly, your solution won't do the trick for me. I don't want to delay acknowledgement of the event. Hope this time I'd made myself clear.